# Why am I getting an error that says "No module named 'BaseHTTPServer'"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, server, modulenotfounderror

I'm getting an error in my code. Here's the code:

```
import sys
import BaseHTTPServer
from SimpleHTTPServer import SimpleHTTPRequestHandler


HandlerClass = SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
ServerClass  = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer
Protocol     = "HTTP/1.0"

if sys.argv[1:]:
    port = int(sys.argv[1])
else:
    port = 8000
server_address = ('127.0.0.1', port)

HandlerClass.protocol_version = Protocol
httpd = ServerClass(server_address, HandlerClass)

sa = httpd.socket.getsockname()
print("Serving HTTP on", sa[0], "port", sa[1], "...")
httpd.serve_forever()
```

My error is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
    import BaseHTTPServer
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'BaseHTTPServer'
```

Can someone please help me with this? I want to make a server just to learn more about it, but then I get the error.

Comment: Presumably you’re getting the error because that package doesn’t exist. Did you try searching the documentation? https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#module-http.server

Comment: Ok, I understand.  I am also getting an error that says the same, but about the SimpleHTTPServer module. when I don't import it,it says there's no such thing as SimpleHTTPRequestHandler. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think the things you’re referring to are from Python 2.x - these aren’t in 3.x. Look at the documentation on that page I gave you or for examples of http.server

Comment: But note http.server isn’t suitable for anything remotely like a production server